# Merge Laravel Collection Items into new array

Tags: php, arrays, collections, laravel-5.3

I want to merge this collection items :

```
Collection {#1242 ▼
 #items: array:2 [▼
   0 => "1,2,3"
   1 => "4,5,6"
  ]
}
```

Into this new array :

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
  2 => "3"
  3 => "4"
  4 => "5"
  5 => "6"
]
```

Is there any easy way to merge and rearray?
Thank you.

Comment: check this link : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/merge-2-collections-into-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections) method called [`map`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map) and then just [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) each item inside and [`flatten`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-flatten) the result, also using [`all`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-all) to return an array, like this:

```
$collection = $collection->map(function ($item) {
     return explode(',', $item);
})->flatten()->all();
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Helped me to auto tick/untick the list of checkboxes after edit form load. Bravo Nikola Gavric !!!..

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can be used for your situation

```
/*
$collection=[
   0 => "1,2,3"
   1 => "4,5,6"
];
* if the above is your collection
*/

$result=[];

$collection->each(function($item)use($result){
    array_push($result, explode(',', $item));
});

dd($result)
```